# Views: Suggest nodes based on user behaviour and history

Tags: views, users, cookies

I tried to search here and there to see if there's an easy solution for what I'm trying to do but to no avail!

I want to show a list of nodes using views based on user's behavior specifically based on previously viewed nodes and Likes on [Rate](http://drupal.org/project/rate) module, so it will be something like "suggestions based on user".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is known as a Content Recommendation Engine (CRE). There are a few modules out there are provide elements of CRE functionality. See this [g.d.o. post](https://groups.drupal.org/node/12347) for a pretty comprehensive listing, but nothing is a popular, easy, & comprehensive CRE solution.

The most popular is [Similar By Terms](https://www.drupal.org/project/similarterms), but it's a pretty basic and doesn't take user viewing history into account. The most comprehensive are the various Recommender modules based on the [Recommender API](https://www.drupal.org/project/recommender), one of which, [Browsing History Recommender](https://www.drupal.org/project/history_rec), is based off of viewing history, however this isn't an easy solution; it requires a [few dependendencies](https://www.drupal.org/node/1207634).

Note that CRE's are complex; think of the man-hours and money NetFlix has spent for its proprietary CRE. You're probably not going to find an easy/comprehensive solution from a install-and-ready-to-go Drupal module. If none of the above can cover what you need, you're best going to a 3rd party that provides easy integration into any website (e.g. [LinkWithin](http://www.linkwithin.com/learn)).